# jquery indexOf very slow ..any other alternate solution?

Tags: jquery, html, indexof

I try to create search box for selected option (very large data - around 2000 option)

indexOf method very slow ..any other solution ?

Jquery Code :

```
$('#textfortitlesearch').on('keyup', function() {

     var query = this.value.toLowerCase();

$('[id^="checkboxtitlelist"]').each(function(i, elem) {

      var datavalue=$(this).attr("data-id");
      if(datavalue.toLowerCase().indexOf(query) != -1)
      {
         $(this).parent('div').show(); 
      }
      else  
      {
         $(this).closest('div').hide();
      }
}); 
});
```

HTML Code :

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="q1" id="textfortitlesearch" placeholder="Search and Select Expert Title">

 <div style="overflow:auto;max-height:100px;margin-top:10px;">
  <div class="exptspw" title="Electronic Enginnering Expert">
  <input type="checkbox" name="expTitle[]" id="checkboxtitlelist1" value="1" data-id="Electronic Enginnering Expert">  Electronic Enginnering Expert
  </div>


   <div class="exptspw" title="African Grey Parrots Expert">
   <input type="checkbox" name="expTitle[]" id="checkboxtitlelist2" value="2" data-id="African Grey Parrots Expert">  African Grey Parrots Expert
  </div>


  <div class="exptspw" title="Alpacas Expert">
  <input type="checkbox" name="expTitle[]" id="checkboxtitlelist3" value="3" data-id="Alpacas Expert">  Alpacas Expert
  </div>
    ......

   <div class="exptspw" title="Sales Expert">
   <input type="checkbox" name="expTitle[]" id="checkboxtitlelist2431" value="2431" data-id="Sales Expert">  Sales Expert
   </div>


  <div class="exptspw" title="Insurance Advisor">
  <input type="checkbox" name="expTitle[]" id="checkboxtitlelist2433" value="2433" data-id="Insurance Advisor">  Insurance Advisor
  </div>


   <div class="exptspw" title="English Language Expert">
   <input type="checkbox" name="expTitle[]" id="checkboxtitlelist2434" value="2434" data-id="English Language Expert">  English Language Expert
  </div>
</div>
```

I think search process very slow ....any other way to search data ?

Comment: May be you could try `$('[id^="checkboxtitlelist"]')
     .closest('div')
     .hide()
     .filter('[data-id*=' + query + ']')
     .closest('div')
     .show()`

Comment: @Satpal same result..very slow ..searching from around 2000 data

Comment: You are requesting DOM doing some manipulation 2 thousand times, this is what makes it slow, not indexOf() method

Answer (score 3):

`.indexOf` can do millions of checks per second on a current Browser. It's probably some other part of the code that's slow.

Assuming the HTML table is rendered once per pageview, you could iterate through the entire HTML table once at the very start and build a lookup table with `datavalue.toLowerCase()` and the `div` that needs to be shown or hidden. Than just iterate over that lookup table instead of the DOM.

That way you don't have to do the `$(this).attr("data-id")` and `$(this).closest('div')` operations every time, which I think might be the cause of the slowness as they operate on the DOM.

I bet the problem is in doing the `.closest()` and `.parent()` calls 2000x for every search. You could omit these by doing the search on the div `title` attribute instead of the `data-id`; that way you already have the element you want to hide or show.

Comment: any solution if slow due to DOM ?

Comment: Creating a lookup table in javascript as in my answer would use the DOM far less overall. If you use the DOM less, you are affected by it's slow performance less.

Comment: Additionally `$('[id^="checkboxtitlelist"]')` could probably be faster. Try giving the container `<div>` an ID (i.e. "container"). Then you could use `$('#container input')`, which is probably a bit faster too.

Comment: @user3691469 At the very least you could change your selector to `$('input[id^="checkboxtitlelist"]')` to get it to just check against inputs instead of every element on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try the search() function in jQuery

```
if(datavalue.toLowerCase().search(query) != -1)
      {
         $(this).parent('div').show(); 
      }
      else  
      {
         $(this).closest('div').hide();
      }
```

Comment: ..same result ..very slow :(

Comment: I think search text in around  2000 records in DOM , then only slow.                              You store records in DB or Static JSON format , then Use ajax response JSON and append the checkbox format html in that particular HTML DIV.